# How does water-soluble packaging work?

Tags: everyday-life, water

Recently, I have been using detergent tablets in a water-soluble package for my dishwasher.

How does the packaging get dissolved in water?

Answer (score 2):

Polyvinyl alcohol is the material used to make the water-soluble packing. The water molecule is polar (negative at one end and positive at the other). This nature of water allows it to pull the Polyvinyl alcohol molecules apart (which is usually how dissolving works).

Comment: The cool thing about PVa is that it's flexible. One *could* package detergent in, say, a layer of sugar, but that would lead to other problems :-)